# Why does Django update other apps/databases while migrating?

Tags: django, django-models

I would just like to understand something about Django migrations. I have a project with several apps and most of them have their own database. Now, let's say I add one field to the app App_A in the models.py and run makemigrations App_A. Then this runs smoothly and tells me that there is just one field to be added. But when I run migrate --database=the_db_of_app_a it lists lots of migrations of other apps, but there I haven't change anything lately. So, I would like to know, why it does not only list the migrations of App_A.

Best regards

Comment: You can migrate with `manage.py migrate name-of-the-app`,

Comment: You could configure a custom database router for your project with an `allow_migrate` method that only runs migrations for certain apps on certain databases https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate

Comment: Yes, I have done that, but obviously I did something wrong. Still I wonder why Django applies migrations to other apps, when I just run makemigrations for one app and migrate only for one specific database.